# How to resolve a Splint Parse Error for `int32 l[2]`

Tags: c, splint

I have some C code that includes a header for a propriety legacy application. I cannot modify the header. I'm receiving a splint Parse Error for the following code:

```
#if defined(HAS_LONGLONG)
    /* removed for brevity */
#elif defined(HAS_INT64)
    /* removed for brevity */
#else
  typedef union {
    int32   l[2]; /* This is the line that is causing the parse error in splint */
    double  d;
  } int64;
#endif
```

Is there any parameter I can pass to splint to get this working?

The platform is 64 bit but the legacy application is 32 bit.

I'm running splint like:

```
[me@host]$ splint -I/path/to/include -preprox -warnposix

Splint 3.1.1 --- 28 Apr 2003
/path/to/include/some_header.h:7:10:
    Parse Error. (For help on parse errors, see splint -help parseerrors.)
*** Cannot continue.
```

Without -preprox and -warnposix I get a lot of other errors in the legacy header.

Comment: Do you mind showing `int32`?

Comment: @JL2210 It is `typedef int int32;`

Comment: What happens if you pass `-Dint32=int`?

Comment: @JL2210 That worked, thank you. Would you mind posting an answer with an explanation, and I'll award it to you?

Comment: There. I've also provided a link to the FAQ for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass `-Dint32=int`.

The [splint FAQ](https://splint.org/faq.html#quest14) states this:

> 16. I develop code on an embedded system with a compiler that uses nonstandard key words and data types. I would like to run Splint on my code but these nonstandard keywords cause parse errors. What should I do?
>
>     You can often use `-D` to solve this problem.
>
>     If you just want to ignore a keyword, you can add `-Dnonstandardkeyword=` to make the preprocessor eliminate the keyword, where `nonstandardkeyword` is the name of the keyword. Similarly, you can use `-Dspecialtype=int` to make a custom type parse as an int.